# Replace SRCs of Two Images with One Click

Tags: javascript, image, replace, src

I am trying to do something that is slightly more complicated than I am used to, and I was hoping you guys could help me with this one... The website I am developing requires this type of Psudo

```
<script>
function FirstPic(){
        document.titlepic.src = document.rep1.src
        return
    }

function SecPic(){
        document.submitpic.src = document.rep2.src
        return
    }
</script>

// Calling Image Replacements
<img style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;" name="rep1" src="title2.gif>
<img style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;" name="rep2" src="submit2.gif>
// End of Calling Image Replacements

// Output Area
<img src="title.gif" name="titlepic">

<input type="radio" onclick="FirstPic();SecPic();updateProductPrice(this);parent.specs.location='<?php echo $options_item['base_var'] ?>.htm';">

<img src="submit.gif" name="submitpic">
// End of Output Area
```

Comment: Is it fine to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com)? And it is not `visability`. It is `visibility`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the sources of as many images as you would like with a single click. And a single function, you don't need a function per each image.

## [demo](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/HdfAg)

**HTML**:

```
<img src='source-img-1.jpg' class='s'>
<!-- as many source images as you would like -->
<button id='replace'>Replace</button>
<img src='destination-img-1.jpg' class='d'>
<!-- as many destination images as you have source images -->
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var r = document.getElementById('replace');

r.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var s = document.querySelectorAll('.s'),
      d = document.querySelectorAll('.d'), 
      l = s.length;
  if(d.length != l) return;
  for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) d[i].src = s[i].src;
}, false);
```

Also, use a CSS stylesheet, don't use inline styles.